# C, manipulating server/client code to make it write a message on accept?

Tags: c, client

This question uses the code for server.c and client.c [found here.](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm)

I want a server to send a message to a client when a client has connected.

As you can see from the article, what the code does is have the server wait for a client to connect, listens to it, and then prints out the message the client gives it, and also an alert to the client.

Here's what I've tried to do to solve my problem (everything else is exactly the same). server:

```
 ...
 newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
             (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
             &clilen);
 if (newsockfd < 0) 
      error("ERROR on accept");
 else
 {
      write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
 }
 ....
```

And on client side, (again, everything else the same):

```
...
if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    error("ERROR connecting");
bzero(buffer,256);
read(sockfd,buffer,255);
...
```

It seems I should be able to do this with just these couple lines. But the behavior of the code remains exactly the same as the original! What's going on?

Comment: I do not quite get what you want. In the vanilla code, client sends message you type to server, server replies "I got your message", and client displays. This has demonstrated your goal. If you want to change the order of read and write, change your question I guess.

Comment: @CrendKing All I want is for the server to respond when a client has connected. It seems trivial, but for some reason it's more difficult than expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For server, insert

```
 bzero(buffer,256);
 n = write(newsockfd,"Client connected", 16);
 if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
```

after `accept()`.

For client, insert

```
bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
if (n < 0) 
     error("ERROR writing to socket");
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

after `connect()`.

Is this what you want? I think you should be able to infer from the rest of the existing code.

Comment: Aha! Yes, exactly. Can you explain what was wrong with my code above? Why was it getting hung up?

Comment: No. Your code works fine for me. What's the problem? Do you specify same port?

Comment: For future reference, when you're writing real networking code, be aware that `read` and `write` may input and output less than you request.  You need to loop, checking the return values, until the requested number of bytes have been read or written.